# org-babel-load-file doesn't load entire file

Tags: init-file, org-babel, literate-programming, babel

In `~/.emacs.d/init.el` I'm calling my annotated configurations file `settings.org` like so:

```
(require 'ob-tangle)
(org-babel-load-file
 (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/settings.org"))
```

This generates `settings.el` however for some reason the file only includes what corresponds to the first 100 lines of code.

Nothing in the section `Keymappings` is making its way into `settings.el`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

It solely seems to be a problem with keybinding commands. I moved things around and add stuff to sections that work and none of this causes an issue. Yet keybinding definitions don't seem to work with org-babel.

## Settings.el

Lines 86-100 EOF in `settings.el`

```
...
;; Headings
(setq foreground1 "#ea056d")
(setq foreground2 "#e0f200")
(setq foreground3 "#ea056d")
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 nil
                     :foreground foreground1
                     :height 1.3
                     :weight 'bold)
(set-face-attribute 'org-level-2 nil
                     :foreground foreground2
                     :slant 'italic)

(setq org-src-fontify-natively 1)

;(require 'org)
```

EOF

## Settings.org

The corresponding section in `settings.org` is this:

```
...
Syntax highlighting in org code blocks
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(setq org-src-fontify-natively 1)
#+end_src

Load org mode
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
;(require 'org)
#+end_src


* Keymappings
** Switching between windows
This defines easy window switching, similar to my vim setup.
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)
#+end_src emacs-lisp
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `#+end_src emacs-lisp`. This confuses `org-babel`. Use just `#+end_src`.

Use the [easy template](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html) system to insert structural elements and avoid such issues. Source blocks are `<s <TAB>`.